# Rebinding Function to Anchor Tag after Successful Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a an anchor tag on an image that pulls up a menu with jQuery. Once the user clicks the image, the function that pulls the menu up is unbinded from the image (so they can't click it multiple times and mess up the configuration of everything). I'm using AJAX to submit the form on the page and I'd like the function to bind back to the image only after a successful Ajax call.

I've seen other similar questions but I'm not really clear on exactly how it relates to what I have. Here's my jQuery code. I'm not putting all the code but let's assume the AJAX call is successfully (which it is at this point in the code):

```
$('.modify_alert').click(function(){
    $('.modify_alert').unbind('click');
    $('.modify_alert').addClass('submit_upgrade');

        //A BUNCH OF CODE HERE


    //AJAX CALL FOR MODIFY ALERT
    $('.modify_check').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        //post variables
        //MORE CODE HERE
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: 'ajax.php', //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:'text', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //post variables
            success:function(response){

            //REFORMAT UPON SUCCESSFUL AJAX CALL (REMOVED CODE FOR SIMPLICITY)

            //TRYING TO REBIND THE FUNCTION HERE        
            $('.modify_alert').bind('click');

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert('didn\'t work'); //throw any errors
        }
    });
});
```

I figured I could just bind click actions back to the .modify_alert anchor tag after I unbound it. I'm guessing I can't do that? Thanks for your help. I'm pretty new to AJAX and I'm just trying to figure out how to integrate it all together. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$('.modify_alert').bind('click');` `<-` you are not passing the function that you want to bind.

Comment: @FelixKling, ok that makes sense. I was thinking I could just bind all appropriate click events to the .modify_alert selector but I guess not. I'm confused on how exactly I would name the function, call it with the click and then rebind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding or unbinding handler, you should specify the handler:

```
$('.modify_alert').click(function mdfclick(){
    $('.modify_alert').unbind('click', mdfclick);
    $('.modify_alert').addClass('submit_upgrade');

    //A BUNCH OF CODE HERE


    //AJAX CALL FOR MODIFY ALERT
    $('.modify_check').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        //post variables
        //MORE CODE HERE
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: 'ajax.php', //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:'text', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //post variables
            success:function(response){

            //REFORMAT UPON SUCCESSFUL AJAX CALL (REMOVED CODE FOR SIMPLICITY)

            //TRYING TO REBIND THE FUNCTION HERE        
            $('.modify_alert').bind('click', mdfclick);

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert('didn\'t work'); //throw any errors
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes total sense. I need to specify the function. I'll try this now.

Comment: Perfect, I will accept in 9 minutes when it allows me. Thank you!

Comment: Since the OP is a beginner, maybe you can explain what exactly you did and why it works. A code dump is usually not that helpful.

Comment: @FelixKling he understood that he should specify a function when binding and unbinding :) but I have updated my answer. Tell me if I should add something

Comment: @MxmastaMills, what karaxuna did was using a *named* function expression (`$('.modify_alert').click(function mdfclick(){`) (as opposed to an *anonymous* function expression, like you used in your code). The name of the function is *only* accessible within the function itself, but it allows the function to refer to itself, which is really handy. Alternatively, you could have defined the function "normally" and pass it to `.click`, e.g. `function foo() { ... can use foo here ...}; $(...).click(foo);`. More info: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/.